# Maximized Window in JavaFX reporting size exceeds visual bounds of Screen

Tags: java, javafx

Here's a trivial JavaFX App.

When I maximize its Window & press the button, it reports the Window Width & Height exceed the Visual Bounds (Screen Size, less Windows Task Bar) of the Screen by 16 pixels.

The Window is being display correctly & its display does NOT exceed the Visual Bounds.

I'm running the Zulu openJDK 17 with JavaFX bundled under Windows 10.

Here's a revised version of the App:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.*;

public final class MaximizeBoundsCheck extends Application {

    private final Button butn = new Button("Button");
    private final Button full = new Button("Toggle Full Screen");

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {

        butn.setOnAction(e -> buttonAction(stage, e));
        full.setOnAction(e -> buttonAction(stage, e));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new HBox(butn, full), 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }
    private void buttonAction(final Stage stage, final ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == full) {
            stage.setFullScreen(stage.isFullScreen() == false);
        }
        System.out.println("Full Screen...: " + stage.isFullScreen());
        System.out.println("Stage.........: " + stage.getWidth() + "*" + stage.getHeight());

        System.out.println("Screen Visual.: " + Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds());
        System.out.println("Screen Bounds.: " + Screen.getPrimary().getBounds());
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here's the revised App output:

```
Full Screen...: true
Stage.........: 2560.0*1440.0
Screen Visual.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1400.0, width=2560.0, height=1400.0]
Screen Bounds.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1440.0, width=2560.0, height=1440.0]
Full Screen...: false
Stage.........: 316.0*289.0
Screen Visual.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1400.0, width=2560.0, height=1400.0]
Screen Bounds.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1440.0, width=2560.0, height=1440.0]
Full Screen...: false
Stage.........: 2576.0*1416.0
Screen Visual.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1400.0, width=2560.0, height=1400.0]
Screen Bounds.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1440.0, width=2560.0, height=1440.0]
```

And here's a Swing Proggy to highlight the problem:

```
package screensize.oracle18;

import static java.awt.Frame.ICONIFIED;
import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_HORIZ;
import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_VERT;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public final class SwingJFrameScreensize {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        printScreenSize();

        final var frame = new JFrame("Screensize JFrame");

        setFullScreen(frame, false); // TODO <- fullScreen=true/false

        /**/      frame.setVisible(true);
        /**/      frame.addWindowStateListener(e -> {
            final var state = frame.getExtendedState() & (MAXIMIZED_BOTH | ICONIFIED);
            switch   (state) {
                case MAXIMIZED_BOTH  -> {System.out.println("Maximized...: " + frame.getSize());}
                case MAXIMIZED_HORIZ -> {System.out.println("Maximized H.: " + frame.getSize());}
                case MAXIMIZED_VERT  -> {System.out.println("Maximized V.: " + frame.getSize());}
                case ICONIFIED       -> {System.out.println("Iconified...: " + frame.getSize());}
                default              -> {System.out.println("Normal......: " + frame.getSize());}
            }
        });
    }
    private static void printScreenSize() {

        final var screen = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

        for(final var config       : screen.getConfigurations()) {
            final var bounds       = config.getBounds();
            final var insets       = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(config);

            final var visualX      = bounds.x      + insets.left;
            final var visualWidth  = bounds.width  - insets.left - insets.right;
            final var visualY      = bounds.y      + insets.top;
            final var visualHeight = bounds.height - insets.top  - insets.bottom;

            System.out.println("Screen......: " + bounds);
            System.out.println("User Area...: " + new Rectangle(visualX, visualY, visualWidth, visualHeight));
        }
    }
    private static void setFullScreen(final JFrame frame, final boolean fullScreen) {

        final var button = new JButton("Print Screen Size");

        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("Full Screen.: " + frame.getSize());
        });

        if (fullScreen) {
            frame.add(button);
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
        } else {
            frame.setSize(300, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the old code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class MaximizeBoundsCheck extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {

        final Button btn = new Button("Button");
        ;            btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            System    .out.println("Stage.........: " + stage.getWidth() + "*" + stage.getHeight());

            for (final var screen : Screen.getScreens()) {
                System.out.println("Screen Visual.: " + screen.getVisualBounds());
                System.out.println("Screen Bounds.: " + screen.getBounds());
            }
        });

        final Group  root = new Group();
        ;            root.getChildren().add(btn);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And here's the output on a Laptop with 2 Screens:

```
Stage.........: 2576.0*1416.0
Screen Visual.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1400.0, width=2560.0, height=1400.0]
Screen Bounds.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1440.0, width=2560.0, height=1440.0]
Screen Visual.: Rectangle2D [minX = -1920.0, minY=372.0, maxX=0.0, maxY=1412.0, width=1920.0, height=1040.0]
Screen Bounds.: Rectangle2D [minX = -1920.0, minY=372.0, maxX=0.0, maxY=1452.0, width=1920.0, height=1080.0]
Stage.........: 1936.0*1056.0
Screen Visual.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1400.0, width=2560.0, height=1400.0]
Screen Bounds.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=2560.0, maxY=1440.0, width=2560.0, height=1440.0]
Screen Visual.: Rectangle2D [minX = -1920.0, minY=372.0, maxX=0.0, maxY=1412.0, width=1920.0, height=1040.0]
Screen Bounds.: Rectangle2D [minX = -1920.0, minY=372.0, maxX=0.0, maxY=1452.0, width=1920.0, height=1080.0]
```

Comment: Here is the output I got from running your code. It is different than your output. `Stage.........: 316.0*289.0
Screen Visual.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1920.0, maxY=1040.0, width=1920.0, height=1040.0]
Screen Bounds.: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1920.0, maxY=1080.0, width=1920.0, height=1080.0]`. My guess is that the Stage decorations plays a part. I am not sure. When I do `stage.setFullScreen(true);`, I get `Stage.........: 1920.0*1080.0`

Comment: setFullScreen(true) is a bit different. I've added a "Toggle Full Screen" Button. In "Full Screen" mode it correctly reports the physical screen size, but when maximized it reports "Visual Bounds + 16", which is wider than the physical screen!

Comment: If you think it is a bug (e.g. maximized stage in Windows 10 reports a size larger than the screen's reported visual bounds), you can [file it if you wish](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report).  Note that the behaviour on a Mac is different than what you report, so I cannot replicate your issue (values are as I would expect when I tested on my Mac).

Comment: @jewelsea Is that the right place to report a JavaFX Bug (the question is: is it a Java or a JavaFX Bug)? And I guess I need to test it with an Oracle JDK rather than openJDK. Which JDK would you recommend for that right now? (17.0.3, 18.0.1,...)

Comment: ok, I confirmed the problem is reproducible with Oracle JDK's 17.0.3 & 18.0.1 together with JavaFX 17.0.2 & 18.0.1 respectively (org.openjfx, from mvnrepository.com)

Comment: ...and it's reproducible with Swing too, so nothing to do with Java FX. I've added an example Proggy for that to the original Posting.

Comment: JavaFX and Swing are different, almost completely independent toolkits.  So, though the cause may be at its root the same issue (perhaps at the OS window toolkit level),  I think they would likely be treated as separate issues if raised.  So I think, the link I gave is correct for the JavaFX toolkit,  a separate bug could perhaps be raised for Swing (I don't know the process for that).  They both use the same bug tracking system so the different bugs could be linked for tracking purposes.  I have no idea if they would be worth actioning and fixing.

Comment: Your link led me to bugreport.java.com which seems to be run by Oracle. I've created 2 Bug reports as you suggested, for Swing & Java FX.

Comment: Following Bug ID JDK-8285982 was created: [link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8285982)

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, microsoft decided it was a good idea to start messing with the OS's rendering engine in order to milk out some performance out of the thing.

Long story short, there's some fuckery afoot which the OS undergoes in order to increase computational efficiency when it comes to pixel-by-pixel calculations which on composite desktops(multiple windows), or large displays (4k and up). (in a nutshell, stuff isn't rendered on a px/px basis, it's based on 'relative' coordinates)

It usually does this independently of what the jdk rendering engine component does.

It's been a while, but as far as I remember, the (i forget the name... prism or something)JavaFX window renderer component creates the window (incl. stage and contents), then it outputs that data to a native .dll which is used to port that stuff to the OS for rendering purposes.

The OS then converts it from specs to a window construct - given the specifications passed to the dll. These specifications include window dimensions and absolute positions.

The OS then places it on screen (but doesn't render).

The OS then starts re-calculating sizes and whatnot (scaling and the like), using the aforementioned efficiency algorithms.

Lastly, the OS renders the window.

At this point, if the stars align and your windows or whatever are rendered based on some arbitrary-yet-os-determined angle which is used to calculate their relative position to one another, you can get cool errors like extra magic pixels.... or for example the Robot class moving your mouse randomly even though you specify the 100x100 coordinate... randomly in the sense that it strongly depends on where your mouse is when that function is called.

If you absolutely want to prevent windows from messing with your windows, irrespective of what the javafx renderer -to- OS binding effects are... use JNA

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/positioning-objects-on-a-multiple-display-setup

But my advice would be to ignore this issue and move on.

[edit] oh ... yea... throughout that delightful wild goose chase I had to do in order to find this stuff out, some of the ms devnet forums I came across claimed that graphics card drivers affect this stuff as well.... so truly consider the advice above.